# Codeigniter No input file specified

Tags: codeigniter

I know that this question has been asked maybe thousands of time before, I looked at most of them and could not fix for my case :s

I have a codeigniter framework installed on godaddy hosting company and i read that i have to create a .htacces file and put this code into:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

But this does not fix for my case, is it that I have this site hosted under another domain?
for ex the structure of my ftp looks like below:
/
facelajm
     studenti
fxclod

and I am trying to get the site following url www.facelajm.com/studenti which opens the main page fine, but when i try to login or reg it just returns me No input file specified.

Anyone could help me?

Comment: Try replacing this line: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]` with this one: `ewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: This is what I have: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]`.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that in certain configurations the CI core misses the rules, the .htaccess I'm using now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
ErrorDocument 404 index.php
```

In my case (dev: a subfolder, prod: an "addon domain") the magic was provided by those two extra lines:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Source: 
http://www.diegodicamillo.com.ar/blog/2012/09/19/no-input-file-specified-codeigniter-error-problema-resuelto/

Answer (score 1):

From your question what i understand is you are running the codeignitor in a subfolder("studenti") of the domain("www.facelajm.com"). So the below .htaccess code will work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

And also don't forgot to change the baseurl in configuration file(`application/config/config.php`) like below.

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://www.facelajm.com/studenti"
```

The above .htaccess which you used in your question will work for a sub domain. 
So you can also `create a sub domain and map the folder` to the sub domain and use the code which you used in your question(For Reference i added below).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

And also don't forgot to change the baseurl in configuration file(`application/config/config.php`) to the new subdomain(`assuming new sub domain as http://codeignitor.facelajm.com/`) like below.

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://codeignitor.facelajm.com/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the .htaccess file i have on a godaddy and it works fine:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Your problem might be the RewriteBase line if codeigniter is not in the root.

Comment: what does your original url look like. mine looks like mysite.com/app/welcome (no index.php - welcome.php is a controller file. app is the root of the codeigniter install)

Comment: www.facelajm.com I have put another codeigniter project under this folder, http://facelajm.com/studenti/ this is my site

Comment: ok. so are you going to facelajm.com/studenti. when i go there an app comes up - i don't know if its the correct app, but its an app.

Comment: yes, i am going that way, and it opens the site fine, but when i try to log in it just gets that errot no input file

Comment: you have "index.php" in your app's login action. try removing index.php from the action. if that works, then you have to change the rewrite rule or remove the index.php's from all of your actions

Comment: u mean like removing the index() method from my main controller? why should I do that? i have most of the code on that method...

Comment: no, remove index.php from the url that is invoked by your form when you click the login button. see if it works. if it does then you have a choice - either change the rewrite code or remove index.php from all of your urls in your app.

Comment: btw where do u exactly put .htaccess ?? is it on the same directory as application folder is or inside application folder? i have on both...

Comment: it doesn not work either by removing the index.php from url :S

Comment: it goes in the same directory as the application folder - the root of your codeigniter app.

Comment: strange that i have tried all the possible ways and still i dont get it work :s

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38052/discussion-between-lulzim-and-don-dickinson)

Comment: it is working now if i remove index.php from url, how can i make a rule when i click any button to not show index.php on url?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

> RewriteEngine on
>       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>       **RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L] or RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]**